# Как узнать вверх или вниз крутится колесико мыши (QWheelEvent )?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qgraphicsview, wheelevent

Постоянно выводится **`0` (`ноль`)**, хочу чтобы если колесико мыши крутить вниз, то значение `delta` каждый раз уменьшалось, если вверх, то увеличивалось.

```
def wheelEvent(self, WheelEvent):
    delta = int(WheelEvent.pixelDelta().x())
    print(delta)
```

Comment: А так `print(WheelEvent.pixelDelta())` что выводится?

Comment: И там еще есть `angleDelta()` - угол поворота, который выводится всегда

Comment: PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint()

выводится, если print(WheelEvent.pixelDelta())

Comment: PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(0, 120)
PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(0, -120)
если .angleDelta(), тут я видимо понял куда дальше

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а если заменить координату `x` координатой `y`, что-то меняется?

Comment: если с pixelDelta().y(), то все также по ноль, а если angleDelta().y(), то выводится 120 или -120, в зависимости от направления

Answer (score 3):

> QWheelEvent Class
>
> Класс QWheelEvent содержит параметры, которые описывают событие колеса.
>
> События колеса отправляются виджету под курсором мыши, но если этот виджет не обрабатывает событие, они отправляются виджету фокуса.

Есть **два** способа прочитать дельту события колеса:

1. **angleDelta()** возвращает дельты в градусах колеса. `Эти значения всегда предоставляются`.
   `angleDelta` содержит угол поворота колеса.
2. Функция **pixelDelta()** возвращает дельты **в пикселях экрана и доступна на платформах
   с трекпадами высокого разрешения, таких как macOS.**
   В этом случае source() вернет Qt::MouseEventSynthesizedBySystem.

   **pixelDelta не является обязательным и может быть нулевым.**

> QPoint QWheelEvent::angleDelta() const

Возвращает относительную величину, в которой колесо было повернуто, в восьмых градусах.

**Положительное значение** указывает, что колесо было повернуто вперед от пользователя;

**отрицательное значение** указывает, что колесо было повернуто назад к пользователю.

angleDelta().y() предоставляет угол, на который было повернуто общее вертикальное колесо мыши
с момента предыдущего события.

`angleDelta().x()` предоставляет угол, на который было повернуто горизонтальное колесо мыши, **если мышь имеет горизонтальное колесо**; в противном случае он остается на нуле.
Некоторые мыши позволяют пользователю наклонять колесо для горизонтальной прокрутки,
а некоторые сенсорные панели поддерживают жест горизонтальной прокрутки;
это также появится в angleDelta().x().

**Большинство типов мыши работают с шагом 15 градусов,
в этом случае значение дельты кратно 120;**

> **то есть 120 единиц * 1/8 = 15 градусов.**

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog


class PhotoViewer(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    photoClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QPoint)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(PhotoViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self._zoom = 0
        self._empty = True
        self._scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self._photo = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self._scene.addItem(self._photo)
        self.setScene(self._scene)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(30, 30, 30)))
        self.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)

    def hasPhoto(self):
        return not self._empty

    def fitInView(self, scale=True):
        rect = QtCore.QRectF(self._photo.pixmap().rect())
        if not rect.isNull():
            self.setSceneRect(rect)
            if self.hasPhoto():
                unity = self.transform().mapRect(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1))
                self.scale(1 / unity.width(), 1 / unity.height())
                viewrect = self.viewport().rect()
                scenerect = self.transform().mapRect(rect)
                factor = min(viewrect.width()  / scenerect.width(),
                             viewrect.height() / scenerect.height())
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            self._zoom = 0

    def setPhoto(self, pixmap=None):
        self._zoom = 0
        if pixmap and not pixmap.isNull():
            self._empty = False
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
            self._photo.setPixmap(pixmap)
        else:
            self._empty = True
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.NoDrag)
            self._photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap())
        self.fitInView()

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        print(f'event.angleDelta().y() -> {event.angleDelta().y()}')
        
        print(f'event.pixelDelta().isNull() -> {event.pixelDelta().isNull()}')
        print(f'event.pixelDelta()  x:y     -> {event.pixelDelta().x()}:{event.pixelDelta().y()}')
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        
        if self.hasPhoto():
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                factor = 1.25
                self._zoom += 1
            else:
                factor = 0.8
                self._zoom -= 1
                
            print(f'self._zoom -> {self._zoom}')
            if self._zoom > 0:
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            elif self._zoom == 0:
                self.fitInView()
            else:
                self._zoom = 0

    def toggleDragMode(self):
        if self.dragMode() == QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag:
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.NoDrag)
        elif not self._photo.pixmap().isNull():
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self._photo.isUnderMouse():
            self.photoClicked.emit(self.mapToScene(event.pos()).toPoint())
            rect_scene = self.mapToScene(self.viewport().rect())
            rect_item = self._photo.mapFromScene(rect_scene).boundingRect().toRect()
        super(PhotoViewer, self).mousePressEvent(event)


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.viewer = PhotoViewer(self)

        # Кнопка `Загрузить изображение`
        self.btnLoad = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.btnLoad.setText('Загрузить изображение')
        self.btnLoad.clicked.connect(self.loadImage)

        # Кнопка для перехода от перетаскивания к получению информации о пикселях
        self.btnPixInfo = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.btnPixInfo.setText('Войдите в режим информации о пикселях')
        self.btnPixInfo.clicked.connect(self.pixInfo)
        self.editPixInfo = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.editPixInfo.setReadOnly(True)
        self.viewer.photoClicked.connect(self.photoClicked)

        # layout
        VBlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        VBlayout.addWidget(self.viewer)
        HBlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        HBlayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnLoad)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnPixInfo)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.editPixInfo)
        VBlayout.addLayout(HBlayout)

    def loadImage(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,
                                                 "QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", 
                                                 "",
                                                 "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp)",
                                                 options=options)
        if fileName:
            self.viewer.setPhoto(QtGui.QPixmap(fileName))

    def pixInfo(self):
        self.viewer.toggleDragMode()

    def photoClicked(self, pos):
        if self.viewer.dragMode()  == QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.NoDrag:
            self.editPixInfo.setText('%d, %d' % (pos.x(), pos.y()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 100, 800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]